# How to stream bytes from std::ostream to std::vector<uint8_t>?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for a way to stream data similar to `std::ostringstream` but for a vector of bytes instead of `std::string`. Zeroes are allowed as bytes.

What is the most elegant way to do this in STL?

Comment: Way too broad of a question (with a perfume of opinion). I can imagine a number of ways (`std::back_inserter`), also note that `'\0'` is allowed in `std::string` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t>(std::cout, " "));
```

Be careful : the stream will probably interpret the values as characters, and so will use the character overloading of the stream operator. If you want to print the integer values, templatize `std::ostream_iterator` with an other kind of int.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant at all (ugly is too kind), but works for me at the moment.

I have some testing code that needs to check if the correct (binary) output is written to a stream. I routed the output to a temp file and read that fle back into a vector:

```
std::ofstream outfile( "temp.hex", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out );
prog.write_binary( outfile );
outfile.close();

std::ifstream result_file("temp.hex", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in );
std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> file_end;
std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> file_begin(result_file);

std::vector<uint8_t> actual;

std::copy( file_begin, file_end, std::back_inserter(actual) );

std::remove( "temp.hex" );
```

Now the result is in the "actual" vector and is ready to be compared with my "expected" vector.